# How to hide a single button in div

Tags: jquery, html, button

I want to hide a single button in many buttons in div by using button name. Is that possible?
I tried

```
$("#showButtons").hide('input[name:buttonName]');
```

But it deletes all buttons in that div.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
$("#showButtons").hide('input[name:buttonName]');
```

to

```
$("#showButtons input[name='buttonName']").hide();
```

if input is inside `#showButtons`

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for:

```
$("input[name=buttonName]").hide();
```

Or to hide buttons that are in the `showButtons` div:

```
$("#showButtons input[name=buttonName]").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You will give class name of the button with jquery hide function

```
<script type="javascript">
$('.button1').hide();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use**

```
$("input[name='myButton']").hide();
```

**OR**

```
$("input[name='myButton']").css({
    'display' : 'none'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name='sb_Second']").hide();
 });
```

[Try](http://jsfiddle.net/gbfwG/1/)